# Manipulate select outside a form with DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

Symfony's DomCrawler documentation indicates how to change a `select` value within a form: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/dom_crawler.html#forms.

I am used to Laravel Testing where you can just select a input and change the value: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#dropdowns.

I can't seem to find how to do that in Symfony or if it is even possible. Given a `select` input like this...

```
<div>
    <label>Select the option</label>
    <select>
        <option value=1>First</option>
        <option value=2>Second</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

...where I can already select any of the components with XPath, how can I modify with DomCrawler (Or any other easily integrated way in Symfony Testing) the selected option **without being the select in a form**?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... If it's outside a form, what's its action? If it uses javascript, you'd have to switch to [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther).

Comment: @msg Yes, it uses javascript to act to changes in the selector. If it is impossible to do the test this way with DomCrawler, I will either refactor all the instances in a form or use, as you say, Panther.

Comment: Then, yes, Crawler only sees html. It's blind to dynamic content generated by. It's not even executed in the first place. And even if you move it into a form if you rely in javascript and not form submission it won't work either.